# vue-pdf-embed/pdf.js making range requests but still waiting for whole pdf load to render

Tags: java, pdf.js, pdfjs-dist, vue-pdf

My frontend using vue-pdf-embed lib to render pdf, this lib based on pdf js as i know. I made by backend to response 206 content and with pdf js demo page it works great, making 200 request, then many 206 to get pdf. But when i use vue-pdf-embed, it also makes 206 requests, but not render part by part, it waits for whole pdf load. How to fix it?

Didn't found any props in doc. My pdf is linearized so it is not pdf.